# Does $\mathbb{P}(XY=a)=\mathbb{P}(X=a)\mathbb{P}(Y=a)$ for $X,Y$ id?

Tags: probability, independence

Does $\mathbb{P}(XY=a)=\mathbb{P}(X=a)\mathbb{P}(Y=a)$ for $X,Y$ id?

What confuses me is that I only find this independence result for $\mathbb{P}(X=a,Y=a)$ i.e.$\mathbb{P}(X=a \cap Y=a).$

What confuses me also is the notion of independence or dependence. I.e. if $X,Y$ are id, then the intersection would hold, but a product not? Perhaps my confusion is also about $\cup$ related to $+$, which led me to associate product and $\cap$ as to somehow relate.

Perhaps, because in algebraic product a property of another often (or always?) translates to the other. E.g. "if $X=0$ and $Y=0$, then $XY=0 \cdot 0=0$".

Comment: Please explain why the probabilities that both $X$ and $Y$ equal $a$ would have anything to do with their product equaling $a,$ given that the product of $a$ and $a$ is usually not $a$: it is $a^2.$

Comment: Are you thinking perhaps of the special case that $X$ and $Y$ are both binary variables (i.e. either 0 or 1)?

Comment: @RubenvanBergen, even in the case where both are binary variables, it does not hold. $P(XY=0)  \neq P(X=0) P(Y=0).$

Answer (score 5):

Does $\mathbb{P}(XY=a)=\mathbb{P}(X=a)\mathbb{P}(Y=a)$ for $X,Y$ id?

No it doesn't.

Take, for example, $a$ and both r.v. X and Y having only negative values, with $P(X=a) , P(Y=a) > 0$. Then $\mathbb{P}(XY=a)$ is always zero.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, this is not true in general.

For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are both constant random variables with value $-1$ (i.e., $P(X=-1) = 1$ and $P(Y=-1) = 1$), then $X$ and $Y$ are necessarily independent, but
$$
P(XY = 1)
= 1
\neq 0
= P(X = 1) P(Y = 1). 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Of course not; see @whuber's comment.

Define a new variable $Z=XY$. If both are discrete, we can write the pdf of $Z$ as follows
$$P(Z=a)=\sum_{x \in S_X} P(X=x) P\left(Y=\frac{a}{x}\right),$$
or equivalently
$$P(Z=a)=\sum_{y \in S_Y} P\left(X=\frac{a}{y}\right) P(Y=y),$$
where $S_X$ and $S_Y$ denote the support of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. This is using the fact that $(X=x)$ and $(Y=\frac{a}{x})$ are independent events (likewise for $(X=\frac{a}{y})$ and $(Y=y)$).

If both are continuous, consider the probability that $Z=a$. This requires the two independent events $\left(X=\frac{a}{y}\right)$ and $(Y=y)$ to occur simultaneously. Notice that each of these events occur with probability zero, as they each have zero probability measure given that both $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables.